# How can I tag a Facebook page whose name contains a space using SLComposeViewController setInitialText

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to use SLComposeViewController setInitialText to create a Facebook post from my app. I would also like to tag an organization's page in the post.

The result would like something like: `Having fun with @Cool Org`!

I have been unable to get the tag to work correctly due the the space as if the org name is two separate tokens.

Is there any way to use SLComposeViewController setInitialText and tag pages that have a space in the name?

I have tried several methods to no avail.

```
- (IBAction)touchedFacebook:(id)sender {
SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) 
{
    mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]; 

    //plain title
    //[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Having fun at %@ with @Cool Org!﻿", _linkInfo.linkName]];

    //spaces encoded
    //[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Having fun at %@ with @Cool%20Org!﻿", _linkInfo.linkName]]; 

    //escaped double quotes
    //[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Having fun at %@ with @\"Cool Org\"!﻿", _linkInfo.linkName]];

    //page id
    //[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Having fun at %@ with @1234!﻿", _linkInfo.linkName]];

    //page id in brackets
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Having fun at %@ with @[1234]!﻿", _linkInfo.linkName]];


    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

}

Comment: Same problem , Have you got solution?